# Cannot use LDAC for my Sony headphones

Tags: huawei, headphones

I have a Sony WH-1000XM4 headphone.

On my Android phone I have installed the Sony Headphones application.

On the upper bar of the application I see the audio is sent over to my headphones using AAC.

How can I have it send LDAC?

I have a 2018 smartphone, a Huawei Mate 20 Lite, with Android 10.

Maybe my smartphone is too old for LDAC?

Comment: According to Wikipedia LDAC is part of Android since Android 8. But that does not imply that every device now comes with Leap support, this just an easy option for the manufacturer. I would recommend to enable Developer options in settings app, because in this menu there are some options about Bluetooth codecs. If LDAC is mentioned there you may be able to select it as default codec. At least on my Lenovo with Android 9 I can see LDAC there.

Comment: The Bluetooth codec option is greyed out in my menu